# Missing \endcsname inserted. ...t werden soll

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

ich bekomme eine Fehlermeldung (Missing \endcsname inserted. ...verhindern soll. \parencite{Klein.2022e}) und weiß nicht was sie bedeutet. Bitte helft mir.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,%
oneside,   % Fuer Veröffentlichung
openright,% Kapitel immer auf 
titlepage,
DIV12,
pagesize=dvips,%
headinclude,
footinclude=false,%
cleardoublepage=empty,%
parskip=half,      % typographisch
% besser mit Einzug,
%pointednumbers,   % das macht die
% Komaautomatik 
% dudenkonform
%draft%
]{scrreprt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{10}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{frame}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[
separate-uncertainty = true,
multi-part-units = repeat
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik-Pakete
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %times new roman
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %vollen Zeichensatz ]
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype} %besserer Randausgleich
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{lettrine}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Für verschiedene Farben
\newcommand{\ricardo}[1]{\colorbox{ForestGreen}{\color{white}   \textsf{\textbf{Ricardo}}} \textcolor{ForestGreen}{#1}}
\usepackage[pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}]{hyperref} % Für interaktive Refernzierung im PDF
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Zeilenabstand 1.5
%\usepackage{picins} % Das Umfließen einer Grafik im Text kann mit dem Paket PicIns erreicht werden.
%\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{xstring}


\usepackage{here}%lädt das Paket zum Erzwinge n der Grafikposition

\usepackage{exsheets}   
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx} 
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\scshape}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge}

%\usepackage{index} 
%\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage[babel=true, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage
[style=apa6,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\makeindex[columns=2, title=5.5 Glossar]


\newcommand*{\quelle}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Quelle:~#1}
\newcommand{\Fachbegriffe}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\section*{Abbildungsverzeichnis}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\section*{Tabellenverzeichniss}}

\begin{document}
Das \acs{EZL} wurde nur teilweise erfüllt, da der Zusammenhang zum Ton scheinbar etwas zu schwierig war.\\
Es war schwierig in der dritten Unterrichtsstunde das \acs{EZL} zu erreichen und es zu überprüfen. 
 \subsection{Fehlerdiskussion der Auswertung}
Eine Stichprobe von einer Person nicht signifikant. Auch wurde der Effekt der Ausreißer bei dem Mittelwerten nicht berücksichtigt. Des weiteren wurde der Schwierigkeitsgrade weder der Aufgabe noch der Stunde in der Auswertung berücksichtigt. Eine weitere Fehlerquelle sind $\alpha$ und $\beta$ Fehler bei der Aussage über die Nullhypothese.  \parencite{Kuckartz.2013c}
\end{document}
```

Liebe Grüße und Danke im Vorraus schöne Feiertage noch
ronjon

Comment: Welcome to teX.SE! Bitte schreibe hier in englischer Sprache!

Comment: your document is much too long, it can't be compiled as we don't have the bib, and it doesn't contain the parentcite `\parencite{Klein.2022e}` you are mentioning.   Try to make a sensible minimal example.

Comment: @book{.2005,
 year = {2005},
 title = {f{\"u}r Human-und Sozialwissenschaftler},
 url = {https://sisis.rz.htw-berlin.de/inh2011/12396797.pdf},
 abstract = {},
 file = {f{\"u}r Human-und Sozialwissenschaftler 2005:Attachments/f{\"u}r Human-und Sozialwissenschaftler 2005.pdf:application

Comment: Please post the `.bib` entry in question to the question (in the comments, the formatting can get mangled). But if you want useful help, keep in mind Ulrike's words: Your code at the moment is pretty long and will deter people (I for one could not be bothered to run the code yet, if it had been truly minimal, I'd have done it by now). Please try to minimise it.

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE reproduces the same problem

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The problem here is that you have `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` with `biblatex-apa6`'s `style=apa6,`. **Remove the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` to make the error go away.**

`\DeclareLanguageMapping{...}{...-apa}` was needed in very old versions of `biblatex-apa` (with `style=apa,`), but hasn't been needed since November 2017. It should be removed even with `biblatex-apa`, but it may cause errors or undesirable side effects with other styles.